# Very simple WebView crashes under API 23 Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have just created an API 23 emulator on my machine:

- HAXM: v1.4 with 1GB allocated RAM
- AVD Base: Nexus 4
- RAM: 768MB, and 896MB in a second try
- Heap: 64 MB
- GPU acceleration: no

I tried it successfully with a few apps of my own. But each time I try an application that uses a `WebView` as a UI, the app crashes that way:

[image]

The three first line of this logcat are the only pertaining to my app (highlighted in blue). All other lines do not mention my application package's name in the 'Application' column of LogCat, but one does in the middle of the message (circled in blue).

I can load the HTML code into the `WebView`. The crash occurs at `setContentView(theWebView)` time:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity { 
    private WebView mWebview = null; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        mWebview = new WebView(this);
        mWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", HTML_CODE, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        setContentView(mWebview); // THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH OCCURS
    }

    [...]
```

Using or not using `runOnUiThread()` to run `mWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL()` produces exactly the same result, which is expected as `onCreate()` is actually on the UI thread.

The html code I am using does not change anything. In the case above, the `HTML_CODE` variable contains this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The app runs perfectly, even with a more advanced HTML+CSS+JS+JS<->Java binding code on all the API 17 and 19 devices and emulators I tried. This is where I'm puzzled. I didn't have a chance to try with an actual Android 6.0 (API 23) device though.

**EDIT**

I have just :

- migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio
- upgraded HAXM to v1.5
- upgraded my SDK Tools (24.4.1) and my platform (23.0.1)

The problem still occurs but the log is different, and a bit clearer. There is a `ClassNotFoundException` I cannot explain:

```
10-28 20:26:05.102 2168-2168/com.example.myapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/lib/x86
10-28 20:26:08.583 2168-2168/com.example.myapp E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
10-28 20:26:09.393 2168-2213/com.example.myapp W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
10-28 20:26:12.521 2168-2286/com.example.myapp A/chromium: [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
10-28 20:26:12.521 2168-2286/com.example.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2286 (GpuThread)
```

Any idea? (I'm investigating further so I will update this post should I find anything relevant)

Comment: Unless you have written your own NDK code, you are running into a bug with the `WebView`. There is nothing much you can do about that, other than to experiment with your Web content to see if you can isolate what you are doing that is triggering the bug.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for that CommonsWare. I'll investigate further and update this post when I'll have something relevant.

Comment: I believe this is related to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189040

Comment: @cryptojuice Yes, certainly. I was hopeful as the SDK distribution was updated, by the problem still occurs. `DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp` (which is the same as before)

Comment: @cryptojuice As the only thing we can do is to wait for this to be fixed, I answerd my own question as you can see below. The actual information comes from you though, so feel free to write an actual answer with it. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour was not caused by any erroneous setting of the AVD or any missing prerequisite (harware, etc...).

As [cryptojuice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500419/cryptojuice) mentioned in comments [this was caused by an OpenGL ES prerequisite issue on emulator side](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189040):

> `#8 ...@chromium.org`
>
> Unfortunately OpenGL ES 2.0 support has been mandatory for devices
>   since at least Android 4.0, so we haven't ever explicitly supported
>   GLES 1.x at all and it was only working before by accident :/
>
> It seems a bit problematic that the emulator (without host GPU
>   emulation) doesn't meet the minimum requirements for Android devices.
>
> We might be able to work around this for the emulator at a significant
>   performance cost; we're talking to the emulator team about what the
>   best thing to do here is.

Now this is fixed (SDK tools 25.1 RC1 / platform 23 rev 3), even though this doesn't appear on the ticket linked above.

Comment: I am running my emulator inside VMware so I have GPU emulation off (the AVD won't start if I turn it on).   I have SDK platform 23 rev 3 and I still get the "check failed: kGLImplementationNon != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)" error and the browser won't start.  If I have SDK platform 23 rev 3 is there anything else I need to do to get it to work?